# Need to understand the below code using func

Tags: c#

I am new to delegates. Today I saw a code on this  [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3?view=netframework-4.7.2). AS i am new to c# and specially to delegates, i was unable to understand the below code.

```
public static void Main()
   {
      Func<String, int, bool> predicate = (str, index) => str.Length == index;

      String[] words = { "orange", "apple", "Article", "elephant", "star", "and" };
      IEnumerable<String> aWords = words.Where(predicate).Select(str => str);

      foreach (String word in aWords)
         Console.WriteLine(word);
   }
```

The OutPut of the above code is "star". AS predicate is expecting to parameters but in this case we are not passing any parameters. Your comments will be really appreciated.

Comment: words.Where(predicate) is a short form of words.Where((str, index) =>predicate(str, index))

Comment: Enumerable.Where() calls predicate function and pass the element and index as parameters to it.

Comment: search for C# MethodGroup. predicate here is used as a method group.

Comment: It is documented https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__

Comment: When call **aWords**, program will check each **word** string in **words** array with condition **predicate** func, this will get a **IEnumerable<string>>** result. When call `.Select(str => str)`, each word in the filtered result will be executed as the **str** parameter,.

Comment: @SirRufo. I read the documentation and it is quite helpful. Now i have clear picture of the above code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first, there's a function definition:

```
 Func<String, int, bool> predicate = (str, index) => str.Length == index;
```

which reads as "given a string represented as `str` and an index represented as `index` return `true` if the length of the string is equal to the index otherwise `false`"

When you come across to the enumerable pipeline:

```
IEnumerable<String> aWords = words.Where(predicate).Select(str => str);
```

you pass this function definition above, which is similar to:

```
words.Where((element, index) => element.Length == index).Select(str => str);
```

and as you can see only the element "star" meets that criteria, i.e. the "star" has length `4` **and** its index is also `4`.

In regard to your confusion of:

> AS predicate is expecting to parameters but in this case we are not
>   passing any parameters.

Note that when it comes to LINQ, we only specify the "what" and the "how" is an implementation detail. so in the aforementioned code, the `Where` clause will pass each element and its index to the `predicate` function.

---

On another note, the `Select` is superfluous, just `IEnumerable<String> aWords = words.Where(predicate)` should shuffice.

Comment: the main confusing part for OP is how are the parameters passed to the delegate. You should mention that this is done by the Where method

Comment: Everything is clear to me except one part how parameters are sent to predicate? like is it automatically send parameters to predicate?

Comment: @Aomine. Thanks. Now i have a better picture of the mentioned  code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start to examine this code from the first line.

```
Func<String, int, bool> predicate = (str, index) => str.Length == index;
```

Here we have simply the declaration of a variable named *predicate* This is a particular kind of variable whose value is a function that receives two parameters of type string and int and it is expected to return a bool. But where is the body of that function? Just after the equals sign. The *(str,index)* are the parameters and the body is simply a comparison between the length of the parameter str with the value of the parameter index. 
*=> str.Length == index* returns true if the condition matches otherwise returns false

Now that we understand the declaration of the delegate, the next question is where we use it. This is even simpler. We can use it whenever we need a function that matches our delegate.

Now there is an overload of [Where IEnumerable extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) that expects just that, so we can simply put the *predicate* variable in that place and call the Where extension

Answer (score 0):

In short, the code just says, "Select all words where the length equals index"

```
string[] words = { "orange", "apple", "Article", "elephant", "star", "and" };

// select all words where the length equals the index
var aWords = words.Where((str, i) => str.Length == i);

foreach (var word in aWords)
   Console.WriteLine(word);
```

[`Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Int32,Boolean>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate. Each element's
>   index is used in the logic of the predicate function.

[`Func<T1,T2,TResult>` Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Encapsulates a method that has two parameters and returns a value of
>   the type specified by the TResult parameter.

So the only magic is the `Func`

```
Func<String, int, bool> predicate = (str, index) => str.Length == index;
```

Which (in this case) is just a fancy way of writing

```
public bool DoSomething(string str, int index)
{
    return str.Length == index;
}
```

In essence its just a delegate, unlike an `Action` its capable of returning a value

[Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)

> A delegate is a type that represents references to methods with a
>   particular parameter list and return type. When you instantiate a
>   delegate, you can associate its instance with any method with a
>   compatible signature and return type. You can invoke (or call) the
>   method through the delegate instance.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify it a bit,

```
var aWords = words.Where(str => str.Length == 4);
```

is the same as:

```
Func<string, bool> predicate = str => str.Length == 4;
var aWords = words.Where(predicate);
```

`predicate()` executes it, and `predicate` without `()` can be used to pass it as parameter to a method.

---

With [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) (functions that can be declared inside other functions) introduced in C# 7, it can be :

```
bool predicate(string str) { return str.Length == 4; }
var aWords = words.Where(predicate);
```